# VB String Sequence "!%Z+^"

Tags: xml, regex, vb.net, string

Does anyone know what this sequence would be used for in a string? Someone told me they thought it might be a carriage return but I can't find anything showing this.

I do see somewhere in code where the string is getting casted as XML...is that what it's for? if so what does it do?

Example:

```
aString += "!%z^+Info: " + dt.Rows(index).Item("Info").ToString
```

Here's the XML usage:

```
Dim cdata As XmlCDataSection = doc.CreateCDataSection(aString)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just plain text that only means something to the application consuming the generated XML.

Comment: turns out it was a delimiter for a custom in-house software to indicate something like a carriage return when processing the CDATA section for text output.